# Is it possible to make AUCTeX preview of equations work with beamer?

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex, preview

When I generate preview images (using `C-c C-p C-p`) for the following document, the images are correctly generated but they are placed in wrong places in the buffer.  Is it just me or MS Windows users?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  The \(a^2\) is now.

  The \(b^2\) is now.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  The \(c^2\) is now.

  The \(d^2\) is now.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make AUCTeX preview compatible with beamer?

Comment: I'd suggest you to report this bug to the AUCTeX developers.  Use `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The right function to be used to fill a bug report against the `preview` package is `M-x preview-report-bug`, not `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: I have finished filing a bug report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug that have been reported (see comments)